# Which loop I should use to get the correct result in below C# program

Tags: c#, loops, average

In my program below, I know what happened but don't know which loop I should use. Here's the code. Your help would be appreciated.

Let me know if you need further information to understand my question.

```
using System;

// Write a C# program that takes x numbers as input to calculate and print the average. 
class Program9
{
    int input, i = 1, val, sum;

    decimal avg;

    public void program9M()
    {
        Console.Write("How many number(s) you have for an average: ");
        input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (input >= 2)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Enter number {0} for an average: ", i);
                val = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                sum = sum + val;
                i += 1;
            } while (i <= input);

            avg = (decimal)sum / i;
            Console.WriteLine("The average of above {0} number is: {1}", i, avg);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nSorry you can't find average for one number, at least 2 number required\n\n");
        }

        Console.Write("Press any key to continue further...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Program9 p9 = new Program9();
        p9.program9M();
    }
}
```

**Input:**

```
How many number(s) you have for an average: 3

Enter number 1 for an average: 5

Enter number 2 for an average: 10

Enter number 3 for an average: 15
```

Current output:

```
The average of above **4** number is: **7.5**
```

Expected output:

```
The average of above **3** number is: **10**
```

Comment: `i = 0` instead of `1` ?

Comment: Buddy we are not live debugers, start using your debug function and check what is your problem. If you have exact problem ask.

Comment: Hey man, you are right!!!, thanks a lot.

Comment: you should try to add a break point and debug it to learn more, you can check the documentation section on top for tutorials, you'll benefit more.

Comment: Please try adding some details. Things you could add (assuming you don't have them already) include: what you have tried already and what has / has not worked, small bits of code or error messages as well as any other information that may help someone answer your question. Please do this by editing your original question and adding the details! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could clean that code up drastically.

```
int index = 0, input, averageInput;
var collection = new List<int>();
if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input) && input >= 2)
{
     while(index <= input)
     {
          if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out averageInput)
             collection.Add(averageInput);

          index++;
     }

     var sum = collection.Sum();
     var average = collection.Average();
}
```

You would need error handling.  But rather than do the calculation yourself, you can use Linq.  Which will make it a bit more expressive.  Also, if you do it yourself you don't need: `sum = sum + average` you can simply do: `sum += average` and it will continually add.

You can also use the `++` or `--` to auto increment and decrement.  So, you don't need `i += 1` you can simply do `i++`.

You should also start a loop at zero, since a collection will start at a zero base not one.  So if you're array has five, and you start at one you would only get four of the values.  Since the array initializes at a zero.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is how the `do` loop works.

Change `int input, i = 0, val, sum;` and move your i increment to the top. Also since we're starting at 0, make the comparison of i less than input.

```
class Program9

{

    int input, i = 0, val, sum;

    decimal avg;

    public void program9M()

    {

        Console.Write("How many number(s) you have for an average: ");
        input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (input >= 2)
        {
            do
            {
                i += 1;
                Console.Write("Enter number {0} for an average: ", i);
                val = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                sum = sum + val;

            } while (i < input);
            avg = (decimal)sum / i;
            Console.WriteLine("The average of above {0} number is: {1}", i, avg);
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nSorry you can't find average for one number, at least 2 number required\n\n");

        }
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue further...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void Main()

    {
        Program9 p9 = new Program9();
        p9.program9M();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The best loop to use there is 'for' loop, but with this it also can work.
The mistake you did doing that this way is that the 'i' should be 0 at begin and in while there sould be '(i < input)'. So code with that loop looks:

```
int i = 0;
do
{
    Console.Write("Enter number {0} for an average: ", i);
    val = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    sum = sum + val;
    i += 1;
} while (i < input);

avg = (decimal)sum / input;
Console.WriteLine("The average of above {0} number is: {1}", input, avg);
```

And with 'for' loop which is more common usage in cases like this is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Enter number {0} for an average: ", i);
    val = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    sum = sum + val;
}

avg = (decimal)sum / input;
Console.WriteLine("The average of above {0} number is: {1}", input, avg);
```

Also there is no point to divide by 'i' since 'input' is always the amount of numbers.